# how to ensure data consistency between master and slave in redis

Tags: redis, consistency

I make a program that can convert  numbers to some  Serial numbers  by some rules and  check if Serial numbers is used. And I use redis to do the check work.

First, get num1 in slave. when result is not nil , it means serial number is  used , so  return  'used'.

Second, if result is nil,  set num1 in master and return 'new' (once return , the nums mean 'used')

The problem is that master will crash before it finish the process of sync with slave , so the number maybe not in slave. At this time get num1 in slave , it return 'new',but the num1 is used.

how to ensure data consistency between  master and slave in redis?

Comment: Redis can only achieve eventually consistency. Why not read from the master? Also in order to recover from crash, you should configure Redis with persistence.

Comment: @for_stack  the crashed master may not be able to restart.  Does this mean that  need to check the sync state  before taking further action  such as "return 'new' "

Comment: I think you should write to and read from master. If master fails, Redis sentinel will elect a slave as the new master. Then you switch to the new master for reading and writing. However, you might loss some data. If you want to achieve no data loss, you might need consider some other databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the [`WAIT`](http://redis.io/commands/wait) command - it allows you to specify the number of slaves that were updated with the most recent change before taking further action.

Comment: This problem has troubled me for a long time . Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Redis uses asynchronous replication and it is not possible to ensure the slave actually received a given write.  There will always be a window for data loss.

[Replication Docs](https://redis.io/topics/replication)